# Gitlab pipeline does not read new code on commit change

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I committed my first commit with `branch A` to gitlab repo and merge it to `master`.

I have some errors in `react build` and forgot to add some imports. I added the required import and again committed to `branch A` but when pipeline is running I still getting the same import error, however, in repo with branch A the line code was updated.

I took fresh clone on my computer and change it with another branch C and push it again, but the error persists.

Can someone please help me understand what is the issue and resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is similar to [`react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap` issue 3712](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/3712#issuecomment-487218538) (you might not be using that specific `react` framework, but the general idea would still apply)

> That looks like a transient issue on your end.
>   Try wiping your cache and ensuring that you don't have any sort of proxy there.
>
> I found [this comment npm/npm#19072](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19072#issuecomment-345555468) and
>   `npm cache clean --force` did the trick, and was able to to try Accordion in `"react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.8"`

Comment: I was edit and command all code with missing import, but the problem not in react project. Pipeline not read new line on last commit and still read old code.

Comment: @darmawanzulkifli A bit like https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/37334 perhaps? I see GitLab had some issues recently (https://status.gitlab.com/pages/history/5b36dc6502d06804c08349f7)

Comment: yeah i think that is related issues, i am still try to get the solution. thank you very much @VonC